# how to save a PDF of the web page and send to WhatsApp through a button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, whatsapp, html2pdf

> [webpage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY3Lo.jpg)
>
> [PDF screenshot(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrkJ4.jpg)
>
> [PDF screenshot(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj6ju.jpg)

I have a 'download PDF' and 'chat with us on WhatsApp' button in my website. I use the following JavaScript and HTML codes to convert my html web page into PDF and download through a button.
My first problem is when i download the pdf file, the ending of the first page and beginning of the second page are incomplete (screenshots attached).
The second more important issue is that I want to be able to send the downloaded PDF file directly to the WhatsApp number through a button. Currently the file downloads alright but i have to manually send it to the given WhatsApp number by attaching the file.
The chat on whatsApp button only opens the whatsapp on mobile phone.

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('downloadButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
    invoice = document.getElementById('fullPage');

    console.log(invoice);
    console.log(window);
    var opt = {
      margin:       1,
      filename:     'TileEstimate1.pdf',
      image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
      html2canvas:  { scale: 1, scrollY: 0 },
      jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
    };
    html2pdf().from(invoice).set(opt).save();
  });
}
```